# Copy Azure Blob and its metadata

Tags: c#, azure, metadata, blob

So I would like to copy an Azure blob and its metadata to a new blob.
I have the method

```
public void CopyBlob(CloudBlockBlob blob, CloudBlockBlob newBlob)
{
     CopyStatus copy = CopyStatus.Pending;
     while (copy != CopyStatus.Success)
     {
           newBlob.StartCopyFromBlob(blob);
           copy = CheckIsDoneCopying(newBlob, "MyContainerName");
     }
}

public CopyStatus CheckIsDoneCopying(CloudBlockBlob blob, string containerName)
{
    while (blob.CopyState.Status == CopyStatus.Pending)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
        blob = GetBlob(blob.Name, containerName);
    }
    return blob.CopyState.Status;
}
```

These methods work fine for copying a blob but doesn't copy existing metadata from my existing blob to the new one. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the REST API documentation for [`Copy Blob`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd894037.aspx) one thing caught my eye (Under `Request Headers` section, `x-ms-meta-name:value`):

> If no name-value pairs are specified, the operation will copy the
>   source blob metadata to the destination blob. If one or more
>   name-value pairs are specified, the destination blob is created with
>   the specified metadata, and metadata is not copied from the source
>   blob.

Now when I took a look at your source code, you're actually setting the metadata on the new blob before copying.

```
newBlob.FetchAttributes();
if (newBlob.Metadata.ContainsKey(StorageManager.IsLive))
{
    newBlob.Metadata[StorageManager.IsLive] = "N";
}
else
{
    newBlob.Metadata.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(StorageManager.IsLive, "N"));
}
```

Since metadata already exists for the new blob, the copy blob operation will not copy the metadata from source blob to the destination.

If you remove the code above, the metadata from source blob should be copied over to the new blob.

Answer (score 1):

So I had to implement this myself. I thought there would be an easier way to do this through an option on the `CopyFromBlob` method but apparently not.
So after the blob is done copying add:

```
blob.FetchAttributes();
foreach (var attribute in blob.Metadata)
{
    if (newBlob.Metadata.ContainsKey(attribute.Key))
    {
         newBlob.Metadata[attribute.Key] = attribute.Value;
    }
    else
    {
         newBlob.Metadata.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(attribute.Key, attribute.Value));
    }
}
newBlob.SetMetadata();
```

and this will copy across all the metadata from the old blob to the new.

Comment: I don't think it is necessary. Copy blob operation copies the metadata of the source blob to the destination blob (Please see `x-ms-meta-name:value` in `Request Headers` section here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd894037.aspx). Can you share the code as to how you're creating an instance of newBlob? Also, I tried copying a blob and it copied the metadata from source to destination properly.

Comment: @gauravMantri I have saved my actual code [http://txs.io/Eczb](http://txs.io/Eczb) without my new metadata `foreach` `newBlob.Metadata` only equals 1 (IsLive property) and so any existing metadata has not been copied over. Bug in the API perhaps? or incorrect usage?

Comment: @gauravMantri I have noticed my own bug.... I didn't do newBlob.SetMetadata(); after setting the `IsLive` metadata property. Could be a small bug in the API, probably more due to incorrect usage. My method is a neat solution though it must be said

Comment: Quick question ... why are you saving the new blob and then copying old blob over it?

Comment: @GauravMantri that's a good question... and honestly I don't know. I need to look at that

Comment: Looking at your code, you're making too many calls to storage which are really not required IMHO. If I understand correctly, here's what you want to do: You want to copy a blob in the same container. If the blob exists, you want to take a snapshot of it before overwriting and then copy the blob. Once the blob is copied, you want to update it's metadata to some new value. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @GauravMantri yes thats exactly what I need to do. I must say my storage requests do seem to be rather high. The only problem I foresaw which is why I create the empty blob is that a lot of my code depends on the IsLive property existing in the metadata. If a blob exists without that then code could throw an error

Comment: Took another look at your code and now I see why the metadata is not copied over. Let me add that as an answer in next few minutes.